# Thinking of switching from mac to windows, need a little guidance

Tags: platforms

Looking to switch to Win7 as machines are cheaper,  easier to repair and as a web developer, I wouldn't have to emulate IE anymore.

I want as smooth a transition as possible, so what would be the closest match to my current stack of apps.

MAMP
TextMate
Transmit
Filemerge (for use with GIT DIFF's)

Comment: Considered installing Windows 7 in Boot Camp, and then use e.g. VMWare FUsion to run the Windows instance "inside" OS X?

Comment: What's wrong with getting a second, cheap Windows computer just for testing?

Comment: Nothing, just I have tried and am failing to get a £600 machine working as a hackintosh, this is plan C (plan B is not quite done with yet)

Comment: fuzz, hackintoshes are only for fun (i.e. if your time is for free).  Consider picking up a used Intel-based Mac Mini instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my usual tools (which is a matter of taste) are:

WAMP, Notepad++, FileZilla, WinMerge.

- Notepad++ is less powerful than TextMate for app programming, but has interesting features for web development.
- FileZilla is too powerful, so you'll likely find the interface cluttered. But it should work with any server.
- WinMerge is much better than FileMerge, the interface is correct (much easier than KDiff3 for instance).

Comment: I assume WinMerge can be connected with GIT to fire when you run a diff?

Comment: I'm not using GIT myself, but it has excellent integration with other tools (like SVN and Hg for my part), so it should be easy for GIT too.

Comment: Git is sub-par supported yet on Windows

Comment: As I said, I use SVN (TortoiseSVN) and Mercurial (TortoiseHg), which are very good tools on Windows, so, no advice on Git tools from me.

Comment: @Thorbjørn not really. Install msysgit and you have everything you have under *nix or mac. If you're a console addict like I am, install Console2 for tabbed console etc, easy copy-pasting, .. Then combine this with TortoiseGit or GitExtension and you have a nice UI too.

Comment: Poor GIT support? This could be a none starter!!

Comment: @stijn, msysgit works quite poorly with e.g. Eclipse, and is simply not as mature as under Unix.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows version of TextMate is probably [e Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/). It has support for TextMate bundles.

For MAMP, there is some options. [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) are some of them.

For Transmit, I would recommend [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), though it isn't as nice as Transmit at all!

Comment: I used to be enthusiastic about E text editor, too. By now, I am forced to consider it vaporware. It started out great, with many nice features. But glaring bugs did not get fixed and TextMate bundle compatibility is still spotty. Personally, I'd recommend learning a new text editor over E, even though regretfully. For example, try vico, or sublime text

Comment: @Paper - There's an app that's even more vaporware-like than TextMate? That's a scary thought…

Comment: @Dori: The thing is, Textmate still has a huge following, and the money to pay one full time developer. As far as I know, he *is* still working on Textmate 2, even though his vision of it might not comply with my vision of it. E however does not have that kind of money. Go figure. (And, Textmate 1 is reasonably bug-free and remaining bugs do get fixed every once in a while. E is neither bug-free nor do bugs get fixed.)